# Grails REST spring security plugin version 2.0.0.M1 throwing UnsupportedClassVersionError RestOauthUrlMappings

Tags: rest, spring-security, grails-3.0.9

I am trying to use the grails rest plugin version 2.0.0.M1 with grails 3.x application.
Added the grails rest plugin dependency in build.gradle

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M1"
```

Getting UnsupportedClassVersionError when trying to run the grails application

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: RestOauthUrlMappings : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0      
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObjectAbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBeanAbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBeanAbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refreshAbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
Exception in thread "main" at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix is to use the spring-security-rest:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT plugin version and add below repository in build.gradle file.

maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local" }

The issue will be fixed permanently in future releases